# Using .aspx pages as an HTML template outside of an ASP.NET 3.5 HTTP request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I need to generate a block of HTML for use by an asynchronous operation triggered by an HTTP request (I am calling the Facebook API in response to an HTTP request, with the HTML block as a parameter). I already have an .aspx page that generates the HTML required, and would like to reuse that code.

I see three options, none of which I want to do:

1. Re-write the functionality currently in the .aspx page into a .NET function that returns the HTML. I don't want to spend the time re-writing it unless absolutely necessary. Also, the .NET code to produce the HTML will be much less maintainable than the .aspx markup to do so (yes, even with XML literals).
2. When I need the block of HTML, make an HTTP request to the .aspx page on the local server. The inefficiency of this does not concern me, but the design compromise does. Because of how the application is structured, I would have to litter my .aspx code with:

   if(localRequest)
   {doOneThing();}
   else
   {doTheOtherThing();}

   which I don't want to do.
3. Create an ASP.NET application host to spit out these chunks of HTML. I'd imagine that this would improve on the efficiency of 2, but not the complexity.

Are there other alternatives? The ideal would be instantiating the .aspx page class and executing it with a mocked up HttpRequest or HttpContext. Can this be done, and is it worth the hassle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two related but distinct parts to this problem:

a) how do you ensure that an asynchronous operation has a valid HttpContext?

b) how can you get the HTML output of an ASPX execution returned as a string?

For (a), it depends on how you're invoking the async operation.  Unfortunately, in .NET there are [quite a few ways to do async operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx).  But if you want to propagate HttpContext to the async code, there's only one good option: the [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkasytyf.aspx).  Although IMHO the event-based async pattern has some drawbacks (e.g. no "wait" operations, hard to sync multiple threads, need to refactor your code, etc.) it does a really cool thing of integrating cleanly with ASP.NET async pages and ensuring that the right context is set up when your callback gets control.

So in other words, propagating context only works (without doing a lot of extra work, that is) if you're playing by the rules set up for ASP.NET Async Pages. Here's an article on [async pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx#S2) if you're not familiar.  Here's [another post](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/fritz/archive/2004/10/19/2892.aspx) that is useful.  In a nutshell, you split page processing into three stages:
1) set up for long-running operations
2) kick off long-running operations (e.g. to get your expensive data)
3) ASP.NET will call your Page_PreRenderComplete handler once all long-running operations are complete.  from here, you can bind your data and render your HTML.

What may make this hard is that often you'll need to re-factor existing code since you need to segregate fetching the data from binding the data.

Now, on to (b) above: once you have context, the other question is how to get your page output into a string. There are a few ways to do this too, but perhaps the easiest is to encapsulate the stuff you want to output into a user control (.ASCX) and then follow the instructions in this blog post: http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/render-control-as-string/. See [this post](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2007/10/19/Render-User-Control-as-String-Template.aspx) if you need data binding too.

Comment: A very clear and well referenced answer. Unfortunately, I don't think I play by the rules required to work with async pages in your part a). However, your solution for part b) is precisely what I require. Many thanks.

Comment: thanks!  BTW, keep in mind that (b) above isn't a magic solution to the problem of how to get a valid HttpContext from an async thread. Only ASP.NET async pages (or some heavy lifting on your end) can propagate the context correctly to another thread. That said, if you now don't need another thread because you have (b), then you're all set!